# Set timer before Function starts running

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, frontend

```
const onToggle = (id) => {
    setActive(id === active ? null : id);
    scroller.scrollTo(id, {
      smooth: true,
      duration: 500,
      spy: true,
      exact: true,
      offset: -15,
    });
  };
```

How do I set a 0.5s delay before `scroller.scrollTo` starts running? I need it to wait before it decides where to scroll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want delay 0.5s, you can use `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  scroller.scrollTo(id, {
    smooth: true,
    duration: 500,
    spy: true,
    exact: true,
    offset: -15,
  });
}, 500);
```